# Invocation fails only in simulator of smart home actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I followed Google's [example](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs) and create a smart home action and add a table lamp device to the smart home server.

With "turn on the table lamp", invocation only fails in simulator. It does respond to the assistant on my phone and shows a brightness control.

In simulator, it showed "Sure, turning the table lamp on." in displayText, but response is still "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again."
The console of my server did show a success response to Device Exec api.

I read some Stackoverflow questions and tried the following things:

1. I link my test account to the action on my phone.
2. In Chrome, I only login one account, and simulator also shows an account being linked.
3. I fill in all information in Directory information
4. Use "turn on the table lamp" directly without saying "talk to...(action name)"

What maybe a possible reason for it? Is there anything I can try?
Thanks.

This is the screenshot of simulator
[image: Simulator screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the simulator. You can test on-device using a phone, smart speaker, or any other Assistant surface that is connected to the Google account you're using to test.

Comment: Just read your comment in an 2017 issue on GitHub. That's quite a while back. Thanks.